# Can $X - Y A^\dagger Y^T\succ0$ be written as an LMI where $A^\dagger$ is a pseudoinverse?

Tags: convex-optimization, block-matrices, pseudoinverse, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

I have the constraint

\begin{align}
X - Y A^\dagger Y^T\succ0,
\end{align}

where $A^\dagger$ is the pseudoinverse of $A\succeq0$. Can we still use the Schur complement to write the constraint as an LMI?

Explicitly, can we show something like:

\begin{align}
X - Y A^\dagger Y^T\succeq0 &\iff \begin{pmatrix}X&Y\\Y^T&A\end{pmatrix}\succeq0
\end{align}

**Answer:** It is true only when $A$ is invertible, please see answer below on the general case.

Comment: The Schur complement can be derived using the pseudoinverse.  See the textbook by Boyd and Vandenberghe.

Comment: Thanks @BrianBorchers. Their treatment does not answer my question since I am trying to represent it as an LMI. I edited the question.

Comment: In appendix A of Boyd and Vandenberghe the characterization is given on page 651.  The block matrix is PSD if and only if the A block is positive semidefinite, the Schur complement is PSD, and $(I-AA^{\dagger})B=0$.  Note that you will not get that $X-YA^{\dagger}Y^{T}$ is strictly positive definite.

Comment: Thanks @BrianBorchers, but I don't know how to represent the additional $(I-AA^\dagger)B=0$ constraint as an LMI (in $A$).

Comment: The $B$ here is what you've called $Y$.  What do you know about $Y$?

Comment: It is a rectangular real matrix which is part of the optimization. @BrianBorchers

Comment: In general, that isn't going to be enough.

Comment: Can you please provide some direction or conditions in which this condition becomes linear? @BrianBorchers

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2913018/339790

Comment: Is $A$ known, or a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in the general case where $A\succeq0$ may not be invertible there is an orthogonality condition that reads as follows:
\begin{align}
X-YA^\dagger Y^T\succeq0 \ \ \text{and}\ \  Y(I - A A^\dagger)=0 \iff \begin{pmatrix} X&Y\\ Y^T &A\end{pmatrix}\succeq0.
\end{align}